# Capitalize first letter ONLY of a string in Python

Tags: python, string, capitalize

I'm trying to write a single line statement that assigns the value of a string to a variable after having ONLY the first letter capitalized, and all other letters left unchanged.

Example, if the string being used were:

```py
myString = 'tHatTimeIAteMyPANTS'
```

Then the statement should result in another variable such as `myString2` equal to:

```py
myString2 = 'THatTimeIAteMyPANTS'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like Barmar said, you can just capitalize the first character and concatenate it with the remainder of the string.

```py
myString = 'tHatTimeIAteMyPANTS'
newString = "%s%s" % (myString[0].upper(), myString[1:])
print(newString)  # THatTimeIAteMyPANTS
```

Comment: It's easier to just do `newString = myString[:1].upper() + myString[1:]` and clearer. Doing `:1` and not `0` to prevent exceptions in case the string is empty

Comment: Yes good point, I didn't think about empty strings.

Answer (score 26):

Like this:

```py
myString= myString[:1].upper() + myString[1:]
print myString
```